# OptaPlanner: Nullable Planning Variable not working as expected

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am trying to solve a Berth and Crane Allocation problem to incoming vessels. I need to assign multiple berths and multiple cranes to the incoming vessel and I created a ResourceAsisgnment planning entity class for the same.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ResourceAssignment {

    private Berth myberth;

    // planning variables
    private Vessel myVessel;
    private QC myCrane;

    // no args constructor on planning entity required by Optaplanner
    public ResourceAssignment () {}

    // constructor with args for initializing the class
    public ResourceAssignment(Berth myBerth) {
        this.myberth = myBerth;
    }

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "AvailableVessels" }, nullable = true)
    public Vessel getMyVessel() {
        return myVessel;
    }
    public void setMyVessel(Vessel myVessel) {
        this.myVessel = myVessel;
    }

   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "AvailableCranes" }, nullable = true)
    public QC getMyCrane() {
        return myCrane;
    }
    public void setMyCrane(QC myCrane) {
        this.myCrane = myCrane;
    }

    public Berth getMyberth() {
        return myberth;
    }
    public void setMyberth(Berth myberth) {
        this.myberth = myberth;
    }
}
```

I am initializing the class with berth data, hence I am essentially assigning berths to vessels and QCs.

I have a hard rule that states if a vessel is being assigned anything less than its required number of berths (which is a class attribute for the vessel) it has to be penalized. This rule is also considering the vessels that are not being assigned any berths, which I don't want to consider. It is ok for a vessel to not be assigned any berths but it cant get less than what is the require number of berths- which is why I set
`nullable = true` on the vessel.

This is how my rule looks:

```
rule "no assigning below the number of berths required"
        salience 1
    when
        $vessel: Vessel($vesselName:vesselName, $berthsRequired: berthsRequired)
        $berthsAssignedToVessel : Number(intValue<$berthsRequired) from accumulate(
            ResourceAssignment(myVessel!=null, myVessel == $vessel),
            count(1)
        )
    then
        int distanceToBerths = Math.abs($berthsAssignedToVessel.intValue() - $berthsRequired);
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -distanceToBerths);
end
```

I am not sure if the rule definition is wrong but the rule is being broken and it is also penalizing vessels that are not being assigned any berths.

Please help me on how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: FWIW: In normal overconstrained-planning (see docs section and PAS example), all constraints ignore null assignments, except for a medium constraint that penalize all null assignments.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Are you asking me to write a medium constraint that penalizes the null assignments instead of a hard constraint?

Comment: Also, in my case, the departure of the vessel depends on how many cranes I am assigning to it (not fixed unlike in PAS example). Could you provide me some ideas on how I can go about it? Thank you!